# How to calculate and compare dates in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, timestamp, nsdate

I have a unixTimeStamp date value. I have converted it to NSDate: 
example :

> 1582118428  =>  2020-02-19 13:20:28 +0000

Works fine. Code where I do converting:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1582118428)
let dateTimeNow = NSDate()
```

**Question :** *How can I compare dates, how to for example print("OK") if `date` was 5 hours older than `dateTimeNow` or 10 days older than `dateTimeNow`?*

Comment: And don't use NSDate, use Date instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as

```
extension Date {
  func daysFromToday() -> Int {
    return abs(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day!)
  }
}
```

You can call this as

```
if someDate.daysFromToday() >= 10 {
  // your code
}
```